# Inequality on sum and difference of two unimodular complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given two complex numbers $z,w$  with unit modulus (i.e., $ |z|=|w|=1$), which of the following statements will always be correct?
>
> a.) $|z+w|\lt\sqrt2$ and $|z-w|\lt\sqrt2$
>
> b.) $|z+w|\le\sqrt2$ and $|z-w|\ge\sqrt2$
>
> c.)  $|z+w|\ge\sqrt2$ or $|z-w|\ge\sqrt2$
>
> d.) $|z+w|\lt\sqrt2$ or $|z-w|\lt\sqrt2$
>
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2016.pdf) [ISI entrance examination]

It is a multiple choice question and only one option is correct.

My approach: As modulus of $z$ and $w$ is 1. Let $z=e^{i\alpha_1}$ and  $w=e^{i\alpha_2}$. Now,

$$|z+w|= |e^{i\alpha_1}+e^{i\alpha_2}|$$

$$|z+w|=|2 cos(\frac{\alpha_1-\alpha_2}{2})e^{\frac{i(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}{2}}|$$

$$|z+w|=2 |cos(\frac{\alpha_1-\alpha_2}{2})|$$

I don't know how to proceed after this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MartinR You are right, but these are the options given in the question.

Comment: @user376343 yeah, by using triangle inequality we know that this is the range of $|z+w|$. But these are the same options as given in the original paper and the answer is given as option C.

Comment: Could there be a typo and it is c.)  $|z+w|\ge\sqrt2$ **or**  $|z-w|\ge\sqrt2$ ?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah the answer is given as C. maybe there is some typo, i don't know.

Comment: @MartinR I have cross verified with the original question paper and edited the question. I think there is a printing mistake in my book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(C) holds as a consequence of the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):

$$
 |z+w|^2 + |z-w|^2 = 2(|z|^2+|w|^2) = 4 
$$
so that at least one of  $|z+w|^2$ or $|z-w|^2$ must be $\ge 2$.

I leave it to you to find counterexamples for (A), (B), and (D). These can easily be found by choosing $z, w$ from $-1, 1, i$.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me 

Comment: @Buraian: No problem! I don't think that this can be solved with the triangle inequality alone, because it becomes wrong with other norms which are not induced by an inner product. Try it with $\Vert x+iy \Vert = (x^4+y^4)^{1/4}$.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding this part of your comment : "because it becomes wrong with other norms which are not induced by an inner product.". Could you explain in a bit more detail? If I understood correctly, those concepts you mentioned are from linear algebra, are those necessary for speaking of length of complex numbers?/ How do they help us here?

Comment: @Buraian: The parallelogram law does not hold for arbitrary norms, but only if the norm is related to an inner product. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces